# Is it possible to control the size of a TAB character in a Flash/Flex TextField?

Tags: actionscript, tabs, textfield

I figured out how to get a TextField to maintain focus when the tab key is pressed (using an event listener on FocusEvent.KEY_FOCUS_CHANGE), but what I'd like to do is control the size of the tab character in the TextField so that it is equal to five spaces. (I would just insert five spaces when the tab key is pressed, however due to requirements this is not an option.) Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

As you can see the TextFormat class have an indent property :
http://livedocs.adobe.com/flash/9.0_fr/ActionScriptLangRefV3/flash/text/TextFormat.html#indent

You can modify the value of the indent in your event handler.

Can you copy/paste the code you're using? Which version of AS do you use?